# Set Default Document when deploying Web Application with Visual Studio Setup Project?

Tags: visual-studio, iis

I have created a Setup Project to deploy a Silverlight + WCF web app.  Everything works nicely, except that the Application is created with a Default Document of `default.aspx`.

Could someone please tell me how - or even whether it's possible - to set the Setup Project to specify that Default Document should be `index.html`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are working in IIS 7 then you can specify this from the web.config:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear / >
            <add value="index.html" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this in IIS 6, you can do it from your setup project (presumably also for IIS7)

In the setup project open up the File System View and open the properties editor of the Web Application Folder. Locate the DefaultDocument property and set it to what you need. If you require multiple values, you can use a comma separated list (bit of luck there, I guessed it would work and it did!)